# How to add elements without reloading the page

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I create view by model Article.

```
class Article
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public List<string> Terms {get;set}
}
```

Terms - can be any count, and I want that they can be added gradually

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>CreateArticle</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            Terms:
        </div>
        <div id="divList">
        </div>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Update", new AjaxOptions() { Confirm = "Add", HttpMethod = "Post", UpdateTargetId = "divList", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter }))
            {
                @Html.Partial("_TermPP", "")
                <input id="count" name="count" type="hidden" value="-1" />
                <input type="submit" value="add" onclick="javascript:plus()" />
            }
```

```
</fieldset>
}
```

_TermPP:

```
@model String

<div>
<input type="text" name="terms[@(ViewBag.Count==null?0:ViewBag.Count)]" value="@(Model == null ? "" : Model)" /> </div>
```

when the click is sent to a form of ADD but I need to create on the Update. How do this?

Comment: "Adding ASP.NET AJAX Scripting to an MVC Project" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381533.aspx

Comment: It added, but the transition occurs in the upper FORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). Also please note that you cannot nest 2 `<form>` elements as you did in your code - this is invalid HTML and might result in undefined behavior.